# In the CodePen markdown editor, can I set a C# Code Block?

Tags: c#, markdown, codepen

When writing a post in **CodePen**, I can set a *code block* with *JavaScript*,  this way:

```
javascript
console.log ("Hello, World");
```

How can I set the code for C#? I tried it with this code but it didn't work:

```
C#
using System;
...
Console.WriteLine ("Hello, World");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, they appear to not have listed C# so far:

https://blog.codepen.io/documentation/faq/what-kind-of-markdown-does-codepen-use/

Currently, as of 27 July 2018, the supported list of languages is:

- html
- markdown
- haml
- jade
- slim
- css
- sass
- scss
- stylus
- js
- coffeescript
- livescript
- shell
- ruby
- php
- sql

You can always try to use `csharp` or `cs` instead, it might work.

Comment: Thanks for the blog link. I didn't find any info about in the documentation. And I tried `csharp` and `cs` , and no worked.  :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, 3 years now, but if you still need it you might try the JSfiddle version for C# / .NET users.

Link: [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/)

I too would like to see someone put up a website like CodePen but for C# developers.